# laravel 5.6 exclude webhook routes from csrf middleware

Tags: laravel, webhooks

I have a route from web.php:

```
Route::get("webhook", "BotController@verify_token");
Route::post("webhook", "BotController@handle_query");
```

how do I exlude them from CSRF middleware?

I tried the following code in VerifyCsrfToken.php but it still doesn't work.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'webhook/*'
     ];
}
```

Comment: it's on kernel middleware, so unless you remove that middleware and manually assign it the rest of other routes you won't be able to do it, but why disable it anyway, does it bother you?

Comment: try just `'webhook'` as well: `$exclude = ['webhook', 'webhook/*'];`

Comment: @GaimZz you can disable csrf middleware for routes which don't provide a token. For example, stripe webhooks when they try to contact your application do not have a concept of your csrf tokens.

Comment: mmm I see never heard about webhooks so I didn't know thanks :D will further look into what webhooks are

Comment: @GaimZz TokenMismatchError always appear when using webhooks

Comment: Yeah my bad, just digged a little bit and saw laravel docs use the exact same thing so it's kinda weird that they aren't being excluded, maybe try composer config:cache, dump-autoload or such things?

Answer (score 1):

Already found the solution. I just removed the "/*".

```
protected $except = [
    'webhook'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to extend the VerifyCsrfToken and have an array of no csrf urls inside :

```
  <?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

 use Closure;
 use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends 
\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken {

protected $except_urls = [
    'contact/create',
    'contact/update',
    ...
];

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $regex = '#' . implode('|', $this->except_urls) . '#';

    if ($this->isReading($request) || $this->tokensMatch($request) || preg_match($regex, $request->path()))
    {
        return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
    }

    throw new TokenMismatchException;
}

  }
```

And change in Kernel to point the new middleware :

```
protected $middleware = [

  'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
];
```